# Passing Data from SpriteKit Scene back to SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit

I've been struggling with this for a while. It's keeping me up at night and making me afraid to get out of bed in the mornings.
I have a SwiftUI ContentView from which I call a SpriteKit Scene called GameScene.
After the game is finished, I want to update ContentView with the score.
This has proven to be much harder than I would have thought.
I've tried @EnvironmentObject, @Bindings, (etc.) UserDefaults, userData (in SK scene)... It's simple enough to pass data TO the GameScene, but how can I get ContentView to update (redraw itself) when the score changes?
I know we are supposed to show sample code, but, frankly, I've tried this so many times and so many ways, I wouldn't know where to start. If someone could assure me that this is possible (in the first place) and maybe point me in the right direction I'll be enormously grateful! (And promise to share my solution if and when I find one. ) Thanks!
Here is my ObservableObject class:

```
final class GameTracker: ObservableObject {
@Published var items: [CompletedChallenge] = []

var totalScore: Int {
    items.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.points}
}

func add(_ completedItem: CompletedChallenge) {
    items.append(completedItem)
   }
}
}
```

ContentView is like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var game: GameTracker
var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        NavigationView {
            List{
                ForEach(selectedChallenges) { challenge in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: DetailView(challenge: challenge)
                    ) {
                        HStack{
                            Image(systemName: game.items.contains { item in
                                item.challenge == challenge }
                                    ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "arrowtriangle.right.circle")
                                .foregroundColor(.orange)
                            Text(challenge.name)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Challenges"))
        }       
        Text("Score: \(game.totalScore)")
    }
}
}
```

In this example, the selected list item navigates to DetailView, where I am able to update the ObservableObject with this:

```
@EnvironmentObject var game: GameTracker


 ...
        let newItem = CompletedChallenge(challenge: challenge, points: challenge.maxPoints)
        game.add(newItem)
```

This works great when everything is in SwiftUI views. But I cannot get the same results when I call game.add(newItem) from a SpriteKit GameScene.

Comment: so typing words here without codes that make issue also would not help you.

Comment: @Hyoryusha I believe `GameScene` is acting like a `model` in your case, make it confirm `ObservableObject` protocol, instantiate  a `StateObject ` of that model in  your content view. As you said you want to refresh `ContentView` only after game is finished, you can make a `propertyObserver` in your model class, that observe for change in game status, and in that property make use of `self.objectWillChange.send()` which will trigger change after your game finished status goes true.

Comment: @TusharSharma, thanks for your suggestion (as well as previous help here on SO). But I'm still having trouble. I've added sample code to the original question in the hope of clarifying the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your `totalScore` property is not `@Published`, so the SwiftUI view won't update when the value changes.

Try this:

```
final class GameTracker: ObservableObject {
@Published var items: [CompletedChallenge] = []

@Published var totalScore: Int {   // <-- Here!
    items.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.points}
}

func add(_ completedItem: CompletedChallenge) {
    items.append(completedItem)
   }
}
}
```